# Compute a relation of `pd.Timestamp` difference to a `pd.DateOffset`

Tags: pandas, datetime

Suppose I have two `pd.Timestamp` objects (`ts_start` and `ts_end`) and a `pd.DateOffset` (`offset`).

**My goal is** -

- to compute the relation of the difference of the `t1` and `t2` to `do`, i.e. (`ts_end`-`ts_start`) / `offset`.

**I've tried it by:**

```
import pandas as pd

ts_start = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=12)
ts_end = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=10, day=11, hour=6)
offset = pd.DateOffset(days=1, hours=12, minutes=0)
relation = (ts_end - ts_start) / offset
relation
```

where the desired output is how many times the offset is placed into the difference, but got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-3485e544dd39> in <module>
      2 ts_end = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=10, day=11, hour=6)
      3 offset = pd.DateOffset(days=1, hours=12, minutes=0)
----> 4 relation = (ts_end - ts_start) / offset
      5 relation

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Timedelta' and 'DateOffset'
```

I can think of a very naive way of doing that by:

```
import pandas as pd

ts_start = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=12)
ts_end = pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=10, day=11, hour=6)
offset = pd.DateOffset(days=1, hours=12, minutes=0)

diff_seconds = 12*30.5*24*3600*(ts_end.year - ts_start.year) + 30.5*24*3600*(ts_end.month - ts_start.month) + 24*3600*(ts_end.day - ts_start.day) + 3600*(ts_end.hour - ts_start.hour)
offset_seconds = 24*3600*offset.days + 3600*offset.hours + 60*offset.minutes
diff_seconds / offset_seconds
```

but thought maybe there is a more elegant and fast way to perform this action, because it seams like a common operation.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `Timedelta` instead of `DateOffset`?

```py
[ins] In [26]: t2
Out[26]: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')

[ins] In [27]: t1
Out[27]: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')

[ins] In [28]: (t2 - t1) / pd.Timedelta("36 hours")
Out[28]: 0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: This is my format, but is there an easy way to transform `DateOffset` to `Timedelta`?

Answer (score 1):

A very naive way to do it can be:

```
(ts_end-ts_start).total_seconds()/((1*86400)+(12*3600)+(0*60))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see how does it solve the problem of getting the relation of the difference of the dates to the offset. It just gives how many days have passed from what I see.

Comment: What is the ralation of the difference of the dates to the offset? it is the length of periods of times between starts and ends passed by offset. If not. can you define it please? maybe. I can help with the question

Comment: I mean that if the TimeOffset is not a day - i.e. it shold be of a float type. I thought maybe there is a more straight forward way for this operation. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated the answer I think it is closer to what you want